# Android journaling application with timestamps?

Tags: android, note-taking

I need an application for my Android smartphone, which allows me to take text notes (not drawing) instantly, among a timestamp, because apparently, an *AutoHotKey for Android* does not exist, which would allow me to

There is already something called "todo.txt", but it is heavily restricted.
It needs Dropbox access to run, it can not run offline, and it has no automatic timestamps at the beginning of each line.

Additionally, it is unable to run from the lockscreen, so I need to unlock the device first. But that is not critical.

I just need an application which allows me to append a line onto a selected text file instantly, and can be accessed instantly.
I could use an ordinary text editor, but that causes files to be saved as 0B on full space, causing the loss of the file.

Comment: I don't know which app has that timestamp feature – but while waiting for answers, be welcome to check with [my list of Android note-taking apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes).

Comment: @Izzy The link you provided is dead.

Comment: At the moment of this writing of that comment it was not; now it temporarily is: hardware issue on the server, being worked on. Sorry for the inconvenience. Will hopefully be back soon; unfortunately I cannot give an ETA. Not really up-to-date, but a copy can be found [in the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160805224455/https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes?lang=en).